# Find the Year of the Question paper it belongs to (Maths 9709 )

Tags: geometric-series

**The first two terms of a geometric progression are  where 0<θ<π/2 
(i) Find the set of values of θ for which the progression is convergent. [2]**

> Which Year Question paper is this? Year with variant Please

Pic of the Qn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22maths+9709%22+%22for+which+the+progression+is+convergent%22&pws=0), it's from S12 QP11 (presumably September 2012 Question Paper 11). Unfortunately, [the link](https://igunioneg.com/wp-content/uploads/IG_Files/CIE/AS%20&%20A%20Level/Maths-9709/Paper%201%20Pure/9709_s12_qp_11.pdf) is inaccessible to me. I'd double-check [here](https://www.cambridgeinternational.org/programmes-and-qualifications/cambridge-international-as-and-a-level-mathematics-9709/past-papers/), but it doesn't go back before June 2016.

Comment: S isn't for September It stands for Summer.

Comment: @user623579 Ah, that makes sense, because if there ever were September exams they seem to have stopped.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was very useful